# Added Subview is not getting displayed

Tags: ios, swift

I have a login view controller. Once Login completes I initialised home view controller as root view controller of the navigation controller. Now I am adding a subview to the view of home view controller. But the subview is not getting displayed. I have tried with with bringSubviewToFront also. But still it is not working.

```
self.home = homeviewcontroller(nibName: "homeviewcontroller", bundle: nil)

 self.app.nav = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: self.home!)
                                                self.app.window?.rootViewController =  self.app.nav
```

Comment: Add the code that you are trying so anyone can help you.

Comment: Pls add code where you add subview to the view controller.